# Extract constraint from generic type

Tags: typescript

Given the following generic type:

```js
interface SomeWrapper<TValue extends string | number | boolean | null = string> {
  // ...
}
```

Is there any way for me to extract the *constraint* into a type?

```js
type SomeConstraint = DoSomeMagicHere<SomeWrapper> // = string | number | boolean | null
```

Comment: This sounds like it shouldn't be possible, because at least the way you wrote it would require a higher-kinded type, and Typescript doesn't support those. I can't 100% rule out the possibility of something working like `DoSomeMagicHere<SomeWrapper<T>>` where `T` is a formal type variable, though.

Comment: Probably the better solution is something like `type TValueConstraint = string | number | boolean | null` and then `interface SomeWrapper<TValue extends TValueConstraint = string> { ... }`, then you can also use `TValueConstraint` whereever else you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the use of it is, but you can extract it like this:

```
interface SomeWrapper<
  TValue extends string | number | boolean | null = string
> {
  // ...
}

type SomeConstraint = any extends SomeWrapper<infer R> ? R : never;
// = string | number | boolean | null
```